# How to change the iOS app's name programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I'm looking for a way to change the app's name from code. I searched a lot and found that it depends on the entry Bundle name in the Info.plist file, and that it's read only so there is no way to change key values.

However, it's default value is $(PRODUCT_NAME) which seems to me as an environment variable or something like that. So my question is, if there is some way to change this $(PRODUCT_NAME) "variable" value in order to affect the entry value too.

Answer (score 16):

The use `PRODUCT_NAME` is a build-time feature. Once built, there is no way to change the name shown under the app's icon.

In short, you can't do what you want.

Comment: This _is_ the correct answer. I'd like to note that (albeit still a far ways to go from programmatically changing the app name) one can programmatically prompt the creation of web apps with variable names, i.e those that can relay back to the app via URL schemes.

Comment: how does Grindr doe this then?

Answer (score -1):

You can change your application name using following steps:

Go to project -> Build setting -> Search for "Product Module Name" and then "Product Name" change name as per your requirement. This works for me. Build your project and run and see changes on device.

**Note:** This will only change "Application Name" not project name and file names.